# The outer measure of a closed interval is its length without Heine-Borel Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I tried to prove that the outer measure of a closed interval is its length without Heine-Borel Theorem. Proving the first part  $m^\star ([a,b])\leq a-b$ is easy and does not require Heine-Borel Theorem.

Proving the other part  is summarized as follows:

(1)-Clearly we have $[a,b]\subset(a-\epsilon ,b+\epsilon ) $ for any scalar $\epsilon>0$.

(2)- $a$ and $b$ are interior points of  any open coverng since $[a,b]$ $\subset$ $\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$.

(3)- The covering $\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ is open. Hence there exists $\epsilon_1>0$ and $\epsilon_2>0$ such that  the intervals $(a-\epsilon_1,a+\epsilon_1)$ and $(b-\epsilon_2,b+\epsilon_2)\subset  \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$.

(4)- Steps (1), (2), and (3) imply that    there exists $\epsilon=min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$ such that $(a-\epsilon ,b+\epsilon )\subset  \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ for every open covering of $[a,b]$, i.e. for any open covering $\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ we have an open cover (not subcover) that contains $[a,b]$. In other words, for any open cover, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(a-\epsilon ,b+\epsilon )$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$ with the following property:
$$[a,b]\subset(a-\epsilon ,b+\epsilon ) \subset  \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$$

I know that the interval $(a-\epsilon ,b+\epsilon )$ is not a subcover but it is an open cover that is tighter than the open cover itself. We can take the infimum over $\epsilon$ which is the same as taking the infimum overall covering.

$\textbf{EDIT: We have}$ $b-a\leq l((a-\epsilon,b-\epsilon)\leq\sum_kl(I_k))$, $\textbf{which implies:}$

$$b-a= \inf_{\epsilon>0}\{ b -a+2\epsilon \}\leq \inf\bigg\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty l(I_k): [a,b]\subset\cup_{k=0}^\infty I_k\bigg\}= m^\star ([a,b])$$

which completes the proof.

Note that I did not use the subcovering property. I used the fact that every open covering of a closed interval contains an open interval (which is not a subcover) that covers the closed set.

Is there any flaw in my proof?

Comment: Such a proof is likely impossible since it must fail for rational intervals $[a, b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The proof does not consider closed sets in general, only closed intervals are considered. Your example is not an interval.  @Mason

Comment: I mean to think about using $\mathbb{Q}$ in place of $\mathbb{R}$. If your argument doesn't use Heine Borel property, then it likely will work when you replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$. But $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so any interval in $\mathbb{Q}$ has outer measure $0$.

Comment: We can not apply step (4) for $Q$. Hence no contradiction happens.

Comment: Step 4 seems flawed. When you do the monotonicity step, all you can conclude is $$m^*([a, b]) \leq m^*((a - \epsilon, b + \epsilon) \leq \sum_{k}\ell(I_k).$$ I don't see where you got the $b - a$ or the $b - a + 2\epsilon$ from.

Comment: Yes, you are right about this point. What if we say that
$b-a\leq l \left((a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon) \leq \sum_{k} \ell\left(I_{k}\right)\right.$ instead of monotonicity?

Comment: I edited the proof according to your comment.

Comment: I think the compactness of $[a,b]$ is necessary for the proof.  So any such attempt will either: (i) use the compactness of $[a,b]$ (perhaps in a hidden way; perhaps Bolzano-Weierstrass rather than Heine-Borel) or else (ii) include a proof of the compactness of $[a,b]$.

Comment: @BilalJafarKaraki Why is $\ell((a - \varepsilon, b + \varepsilon)) \leq \sum_{k}\ell(I_k)$? That doesn't follow from any of your previous steps. It is clearly false for rational intervals too since in this case, $\sum_{k}\ell(I_k)$ can be $0$.

Comment: Thanks,........@Mason

Answer (score 2):

When you write [I've made a small correction]
\begin{equation}
\label{4385212:eq:1}\tag{A}
\inf_{\epsilon>0} (b - a + 2\epsilon) \leqslant
\inf\left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty l(I_k) : [a, b] \subset
\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k\right\}
\end{equation}
you appear to be appealing to an unstated lemma to the effect that
if $J$ is an open interval, and $(I_k)_{k\geq0}$ is an infinite
sequence of open intervals, and
$$
J \subseteq \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k,
$$
then
$$
l(J) \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^\infty l(I_k).
$$
Given such a lemma, it would be valid to infer \eqref{4385212:eq:1}
from your previous assertion that for all open $(I_k)_{k\geq0}$ such
that $[a, b] \subset \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k,$ there exists
$\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
(a - \epsilon, b + \epsilon) \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k,
$$
and I think the proof would be OK - but do you have a proof of the lemma?

Comment: Thank you for this point. The unstated Lemma is a consequence of the monotonicity theorem of outer measuer. Let $A=(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon )$  and  $B=\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$, it has been proved that $A\subset B$.  Hence, $m(A)\leq m(B)$.

Comment: Indeed, we do know that $m(A) \leqslant m(B).$ We also know that $m(B) \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k).$ But how do we know that $m(A) \geqslant b - a + 2\epsilon$? (Incidentally, we've both been writing $a - b$ by mistake for $b - a$.)

Comment: I have reviewed the proof in Royden's book. The author applied the unstated Lemma for subcovers of the open covering. I did not see the difference between the arguments.  \\

 Here is a part of his proof: Choose a natural number $n$ for which $\left\{I_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{n}$ covers $[a, b]$. We will show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ell\left(I_{k}\right) \geq b-a \text {, }
$$
and therefore  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}\right) \geq b-a$ holds.

Comment: I can't find those words on page 56 of Royden, *Real Analysis* (3rd ed. 1988). Nor can I find any appeal to the unstated lemma in his proof. Can you give more details, please?

Comment: Royden, Real Analysis, 4th ed, 2009, chapter 2 p.p. 32.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that edition, nor can I find a preview at Amazon or Google, nor do I wish to download an illegal PDF. (Not that my hands are entirely clean in that respect!) If you believe that the argument in Royden & Fitzpatrick's book supports yours - regardless of whether or not it appeals to an unstated lemma - perhaps you could incorporate an extract from the book into your question.